# How to recover containers and images in WSL2 that go missing after installing Docker Desktop?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop, wsl-2

I'm attempting to use my WSL2 docker containers with VS Code, though I now regret this. I attempted to follow [these directions](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/03/02/docker-in-wsl2) to get everything installed and configured correctly.

After installing Docker Desktop, my previous containers and images are not shown with `docker ls` and `docker images` when run from WSL2. However, there are still many GB of data under `/var/lib/docker`. Is there some way to attempt to recover this?

Comment: For anyone else coming here ... I gave up, and started over ... in my case it was just simpler to do that. Of course, I removed the old data.